# Como aceder a las variables de los inizializers en ruby on rails?

Tags: poo, ruby-on-rails, variables, ruby, variables-de-configuración

Hola estoy intentando invocar una variable site_key dicha varaiable se encuentra en un inizializer:

config/initializers/recaptcha.rb

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.site_key  = 'ClaveDelSitio'
  config.secret_key = 'ClavePrivada'
end
```

Como puedo aceder al valor del "config.site_key" desde otra parte del codigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo como [la configuración es almacenada](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha.rb#L26) en la gema y el [`site_key`](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha/configuration.rb#L40) es solo un `attr_accessor`, así que deberías poder acceder con:

```
Recaptcha.configuration.site_key
```

Comment: Gracías Amigo eres un Crack